# Napili Customer Community - ec 301 redirect to Salesforce.com site. How to set up redirects?

Tags: javascript, customer-community, error-messages, napili

I have a Napili Customer Community in my Sandbox. Its built with custom Themes/Layouts and Lightning Components.

If Im logged in, and close my laptop - When I open it back up, its on Salesforce.com and the 'back' button shows it was redirected there by a ec 301.

[image]

I was guided to Site.com 'Site Configuration > URL Redirects', which is confusing enough, because I have only used the Community Builder so far.

[image]

1. I dont know what goes in the 'Redirected From' field
2. Im not sure I know why ec301 is occuring
3. Is there anything I can do in Javascript to make sure any error codes or logouts go back to the Login page?

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use relative paths in the fields, Ex. from page A to page B, you can read more on redirect rules for site.com [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_redirects.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

the error code simply indicates that the page to which you should have been redirected no longer exists.

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
> permanent URL redirection

According to the [documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf)

> You can also redirect to your own page...
>
> Create a file such as ieRedirect.js and include it in the header
> script section of the Site.com page. The file should contain the
> following code:

```
if (window.attachEvent && !window.addEventListener) {
window.location = '<your redirect page>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the bit of code, that may be the best path.  As far as the error code, I guess thats whats confusing me - " error code simply indicates that the page to which you should have been redirected no longer exists."  ->  It should be logging out with a timeout and going to the login page, so Im not sure where its trying to go.  Hopefully the javascript will be a catchall.

Comment: The big help for me here, was that you linked the Salesforce documentation containing the script, so I feel its not too hack-ish.  Im familiar with that document, but never saw that bit of code.  Thank you!

Comment: no prob, glad it was of help